# webview.loadUrl() problem in android?

Tags: android

I am loading a URL whose datatype is String in a `WebView`. Using something like:

```
webview.loadUrl(string_variable);
```

but it is automatically redirected to the browser.

I got this in my LOGCAT,

```
02-13 14:11:08.586: INFO/ActivityManager(5Cool: Displayed activity com.example.brown/.Bru_Press_MostRecent_ArticleView: 2583 ms (total 2583 ms)
02-13 14:11:09.376: INFO/ActivityManager(5Cool: Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=http://mobile.twitter.com/brownuniversity/statuses/8681812931 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) }
02-13 14:11:09.506: INFO/ActivityManager(5Cool: Start proc com.android.browser for activity com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity: pid=285 uid=10014 gids={3003, 1015}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the same thing happen with a different URL?  I'm wondering if `mobile.twitter.com` has a redirect which is causing the Browser to be launched.

Comment: hey how to rectify that? i want to load only in my webview..

actually i m passing the url value : 
http://twitter.com/brownuniversity/statuses/8963488831


but its automatically loads. what can i do mate?

Comment: i am getting this problem in twitter's url only man.. but how can i solve it?

Comment: This is poorly qualify as answer. Should probably be just a comment

Comment: Agreed that this is a poor answer, maybe you should approve the solution below.

Answer (score 27):

You can remedy this by overriding your WebView's WebViewClient. All it takes is something like this:

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });
```

Just be aware that WebView is more limited than full blown browser

Comment: n.p. I was dealing with the same problem. BTW it helps to revisit your own questions and add solution if you found one. I try to do that when I won't get a clear answer and later find answer somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

you need add setting for app
Follow:

> mWebView.getSettings()
>                   .setUserAgentString(
>                           "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");